# Inserting 500k records into redis using spring-data-redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using redis as a cache and once I am going to be fetching a table from an oracle database then inserting those records into the redis cache. I am using the repositories for both so I am doing something like:

```
 oracleRepo.findAll().forEach(record -> {
            RedisEntity redisEntity = objectMapper.convertValue(record, RedisEntity.class);
            redisRepo.save(redisEntity);
        });
```

However, this is quite slow when I am saving it onto redis since it's about 500k records. I know I can improve the way I fetch from the database and use pagination but will that improve saving onto redis. Is there a way to do a batch insert into redis because it seems like right now it is opening and closing the redis connection for each record it's trying to save.

Comment: How are you going to use this data? I suggest you try to store it in cache in a way which reflects its intended usage. If you need pages at a time, you might store all those values at a single key. The problem now is that you're storing each record individually, so that's 500k round trips to cache (after loading from DB). You could use Spring Cache, or, perhaps Redisson which allows many different types of data which might allow you to store this data and batch it. I'm not familiar with Spring data redis, personally.

Comment: It's going to be used as lookup data so I would need all the data in the cache.

Comment: It's less a matter of it being cached and more a matter of how it is cached and how you intend to load from cache. Will you get home each of these records from cache individually (as you are saving them), or will you be caching many records at a single cache key? Right now, you don't batch your saves to cache so it is O(n) round trips. If you can store all these records at one key, you might loop over it first, perform some basic processing, and finally, write once to cache. Lots of factors here, but if you preprocess your data and wrote to cache fewer times life will be better.

Comment: Unless I am thinking of redis wrong I want to store each record individually so when time comes use this lookup data I can get the single record I need using the key. Not sure if this is still possible by saving all the records under one key. I will need to lookup the data quite often using different keys as well.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, I just wanted to make sure you had to actually write 500k like this.  I briefly reviewed spring data redis and didn't see mass insertion or bulk insertion on their docs page, however, I did find pipelining: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#pipeline, and that references https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert; you might also try StringRedisTemplate as well.  Depending on the data being stored, you might be able to make use of MSET operation which can write many keys at once, if you want to use raw commands.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to batch the responses from Oracle and use [redis-pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to set these keys in redis server.

Sending multiple commands to the redis server using pipeline will allow to keep processing for the batches without waiting for the responses for evert SET operation.

Here is the sample code from spring boot on using redis pipeline:

```
//pop a specified number of items from a queue
List<Object> results = stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(
  new RedisCallback<Object>() {
    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
      StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
      for(int i=0; i< batchSize; i++) {
        stringRedisConn.rPop("myqueue");
      }
    return null;
  }
});
```

[Spring Data Redis Pipelining](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline)

Comment: but if there is connection issue, how that will be handled, is not mentioned here.